# Accidentally deleted customers Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

We recently had BOTs setting up accounts on our website, 2000 or so.

We accidentally clicked delete all instead of delete all visible and lost about half of our accounts.

I have a database backup from a few weeks ago that I can use, what would be the best way to get the customers from the old database without effecting the customers that weren't deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do following:

- create a new temp installation from the backup.
- Export customers
- Delete all customers from current site
- Import from the exported csv file

Comment: Will the customers still be able to see the orders on their accounts when they get imported doing it this way?

Comment: I'm not convinced they would be able to. But Devtpes' solution is the best one I can think of too.

Comment: No they won't be able to see the orders. In the sales_flat_order table is a column customer_id. After the import, update this column with the new customer-IDs. For mapping, you can use the customer's email address which is present in the customer_entity and the sales_flat_order tables

Comment: How would I do this for 2000 or so customers? Is there a mysql command I could run to do this?

Comment: You can halve your work by only importing the deleted customers. For that you have to export customers from current site and new temp installation then compare both and difference will be imported into current site, after that you can associate newly added customers to the orders. To speed up the work you can use some ready made plugin such as https://marketplace.magento.com/magebright-magebright-assignorder.html (check the suitability first as I've never used it).

Comment: I have the temp installation up and I've exported the customers I need. When I trying import the customers via System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles, I always get the same error for all rows - Skipping import row, required field "website" is not defined. The first line of my CSV is:  ID,Name,Email,Group,Telephone,ZIP,Country,State/Province,"Customer Since",Website and an example user would be: 5,"Ger Physio",email@email.com,Wholesale,0830000000,0000,Ireland,Tipperary,"25 Aug 2015 12:46:15","Clinic Supplies" Any ideas whats causing this error?

Comment: Using Import/Export => Import instead of dataflow profiles will be better option in my opinion.

Comment: When I use normal import, I get stuck once I click check data, a "Please Wait" box comes up and nothing happens. I've tried it with only 2 customers to see if the import was too big and it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

The deleted customers' orders are still in `sales_flat_order` only the customer_id is reset to NULL and orders set to archived. That means some of their info is still there.

Curiously after this accident happened literally during processing an order, Magento created the customer again with a new ID and the order went on like nothing was wrong. Thankfully (for me) I was working on a migration tool so I have a list of customer_ids with email, name, and their original password hash. Working out the steps to manually add them now.

---

Edited to add: I have accomplished as much as a repair as I deem practical for now.

- Got list of customers from the Xfer database whose IDs were up to 1053 (the lowest number remaining in the customer list).
- Used Mage::getModel() and $customer to add the deleted customer back to Magento 1.
- Got the new customer id from the newly added customer so I can match to the old customer ID from the Xfer database.
- Updated customer_entity to fix created_at, the website_id, and store_id.
- Updated sales_flat_order to set the customer_id where the email matches the one from the Xfer database.
- Updated sales_flat_invoice to find the previous customer ID and change to the new customer ID.
- Inserted the password hash from the Xfer database back into customer_entity_varchar.

Observations:

- The customers reappear on the manage customers list, only now at the top.
- Previous sales appear in "purchases".
- The "orders" tab is blank. Not exactly sure how that tab is populated and not going to pore over the code unless people complain.
- You'll need to manually make a query to update the website and store IDs. The create customer Mage call I used ignored what I put in.
- Created_at is broken, but it's not exactly awesome anywhere in our Magento.

Comment: orders tab can be fixed by updating `customer_id`s in the `sales_flat_order_grid` table

Answer (score 0):

I would only work in phpMyAdmin:

- restore the backup in new database
- copy `customer_entity`,
  `customer_entity_`* tables (if addresses got deleted too then
  `customer_entity_address`* tables too) from new database to old
  database renaming them like *`_2` on the way
- ```
  insert into customer_entity 
  select * from customer_entity_2 
  where entity_id not in (select entity_id from customer_entity)
  ```
- do the same for all the moved tables

I guess that way all the old connections that are based on customer_id would work (like orders and such)